# Material UI: Style a styled component problem (TS)

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Recently I started to work with styled components in MUI such as:

```ts
const customBaseComponent = styled(Button)`
color: red
css here
`
```

Styling native MUI comps is working perfectly, as desired.
But then comes the nested styling...
Now what I need is to style my `customBaseComponent` as below

```ts
const newStyledCustom = styled(customBaseComponent)`
color: blue
css here
`
```

Any css that was implemented in the first comp and now overriden is not being shown as desired (the overriden version)

Apart of this, tried most of the stuff that comes in the doc but frankly I don't know if either I'm not implementing it right or I don't understand it.
Does this way work? Or I have to swap to `makeStyles`, `withStyles`.. and so on?

Comment: Care to elaborate how it doesn’t work? You could create a sandbox with MUI. Here’s one with styled-components nesting: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-gauss-sicthk?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: So Button is a MUI Component. I'm just styling it  (`customBaseComponent`) to add some different style and behaviour. Then, I need to make another component, which is based on the first one. Once done, all styles that are overriden, they are not applied .